# Define a composite index in EdgeDB

Tags: indexing, compound-index, composite-index, edgedb

How do you define a composite index in EdgeDB?

[The documentation states](https://edgedb.com/docs/datamodel/indexes/):

> The simplest form of index is an index, which references one or **more properties directly**:
>
> ```
> type User {
>     property name -> str;
>     index on (__subject__.name);
> }
> ```

but I couldn't find a way to reference multiple properties in an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `index on (...)` to the containing type, where `...` is an arbitrary scalar expression. To create a composite index it should be a tuple `(x, y)`:

```
type User {
    property first_name -> str;
    property last_name -> str;
    index on ((.first_name, .last_name));
}
```

*[source](https://github.com/edgedb/edgedb/discussions/1608)*